# Check if element is present when using POM

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have an issue finding i good way of checking if an element is present.
I´m using Page Object Model when automating my test cases meaning i declare all elements in a specific class, and not in the actual [tests]. How can i transform this simple method for verifying declared elements like this:

```
private IWebElement LoginButton => driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginButton")); 

IsElementPresent(IWebElement element)
{
   try
   {
    //Something something
   }

   catch(NoSuchElementException)
   {
   return false;
   } 

   return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue not long ago:

Managed to include a retry strategy/policy in it, so I'm waiting for the element to exist in the DOM.

```
        public static void WaitForElementToExistInDom(Func<IWebElement> action)
        {
            RetryPolicy.Do(() =>
            {
                if (!DoesElementExistInDom(action))
                    throw new RetryPolicyException();
            }, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeouts.DefaultTimeSpanInMilliseconds), TestConstants.DefaultRetryCount);
        }

        public static bool DoesElementExistInDom(Func<IWebElement> action)
        {
            var doesExist = false;
            try
            {
                var element = action.Invoke();
                if (element != null)
                    doesExist = true;
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
            }

            return doesExist;
        }
```

And you can call it like this:

```
WebDriverExtensionMethods.WaitForElementToExistInDom(() => Map.YourElement);
```

If the element is stalled or not existing, internally we're going to handle the exceptions and try again.

And because the evaluation 'if the element exists in the DOM' is done when you're getting calling the element from the MAP, we're wrapping it in an Action/Func, this way the evaluation is done in method (and so the catching of the exceptions), you don't have to use find selector outside of the element map itself.

Comment: is this java? Never heard of RetryPolicy

Comment: This is C#, RetryPolicy is something that I've written (there are multiple NuGets for it also).  You can just comment it on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something simple like

```
public bool ElementExists(By locator)
{
    return Driver.FindElements(locator).Any();
}
```

You would call it like

```
if (ElementExists(By.Id("LoginButton")))
{
    // do something
}
```

You can't pass in an element because in order to pass it in, you would have to locate it first which would not be possible (it would throw an exception) if it's not present.

If you are trying to check an existing element, you could do something like the below.

```
public bool ElementExists(IWebElement e)
{
    try
    {
        bool b = e.Displayed;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have already declared my element. In this example, i want check if "LoginButton" exists in the page

Comment: If you are following the page object model, you ideally have your locators defined and can pass that locator to the first method. If your scenario is different and have an existing element that you need to check for existence, I've added another method for that case.

Comment: The same thing happens. I can not get into the try catch method. gets no such element is present exeption on the defined locator

Comment: You need to update your question with the actual code you are using and the result. It's not clear any more what you are asking if neither of these will work.